# rabbitmq-server stuck on startup (then crashes)

Tags: macos, rabbitmq, homebrew

I need to start and work on a local rabbitMQ server on my mac. So I installed it using brew, added it to my path and performed `rabbitmq-server`. It says that it's starting forever, then ends up crashing. I've also tried the `brew service start rabbitmq` command and when I check the status it says it's starting for a while and then it says it's dead.
You will find relevant information below.
Any help is appreciated !

**What I get when running `rabbitmq-server`**

```
Configuring logger redirection

  ##  ##      RabbitMQ 3.8.14
  ##  ##
  ##########  Copyright (c) 2007-2021 VMware, Inc. or its affiliates.
  ######  ##
  ##########  Licensed under the MPL 2.0. Website: https://rabbitmq.com

  Doc guides: https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html
  Support:    https://rabbitmq.com/contact.html
  Tutorials:  https://rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html
  Monitoring: https://rabbitmq.com/monitoring.html

  Logs: /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log
        /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost_upgrade.log

  Config file(s): (none)

  Starting broker...
```

This never works.

**What I get when running `brew services start rabbitmq` :**

```
% brew services start rabbitmq
==> Successfully started `rabbitmq` (label: homebrew.mxcl.rabbitmq)
% rabbitmq-diagnostics is_booting
Asking node rabbit@localhost for its boot status ...
RabbitMQ on node rabbit@localhost is booting
```

It stays in this booting status forever and eventually stops/dies, leaving the server down.

And the error message:

```
BOOT FAILED
===========
Error during startup: {error,
                          {schema_integrity_check_failed,
                              [{table_missing,rabbit_user},
                               {table_missing,rabbit_user_permission},
                               {table_missing,rabbit_topic_permission},
                               {table_missing,rabbit_vhost},
                               {table_missing,rabbit_listener},
                               {table_missing,rabbit_durable_route},
                               {table_missing,rabbit_semi_durable_route},
                               {table_missing,rabbit_route},
                               {table_missing,rabbit_reverse_route},
                               {table_missing,rabbit_topic_trie_node},
                               {table_missing,rabbit_topic_trie_edge},
                               {table_missing,rabbit_topic_trie_binding},
                               {table_missing,rabbit_durable_exchange},
                               {table_missing,rabbit_exchange},
                               {table_missing,rabbit_exchange_serial},
                               {table_missing,rabbit_runtime_parameters},
                               {table_missing,rabbit_durable_queue},
                               {table_missing,rabbit_queue},
                               {table_missing,gm_group},
                               {table_missing,mirrored_sup_childspec}]}}

{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,rabbit,{{schema_integrity_check_failed,[{table_missing,rabbit_user},{table_missing,rabbit_user_permission},{table_missing,rabbit_topic_permission},{table_missing,rabbit_vhost},{table_missing,rabbit_listener},{table_missing,rabbit_durable_route},{table_missing,rabbit_semi_durable_route},{table_missing,rabbit_route},{table_missing,rabbit_reverse_route},{table_missing,rabbit_topic_trie_node},{table_missing,rabbit_topic_trie_edge},{table_missing,rabbit_topic_trie_binding},{table_missing,rabbit_durable_exchange},{table_missing,rabbit_exchange},{table_missing,rabbit_exchange_serial},{table_missing,rabbit_runtime_parameters},{table_missing,rabbit_durable_queue},{table_missing,rabbit_queue},{table_missing,gm_group},{table_missing,mirrored_sup_childspec}]},{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,rabbit,{{schema_integrity_check_failed,[{table_missing,rabbit_user},{table_missing,rabbit_user_permission},{table_missing,rab

Crash dump is being written to: /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/erl_crash.dump...done
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed :
ran

```
brew uninstall rabbitmq
```

then ran

```
find /usr/local -xdev -name '*rabbitmq*'
```

and deleted everything that showed up. Then reinstalled it by running

```
brew install rabbitmq
```

and it worked !

Answer (score 0):

Previous fix didn't work for me - had to additionally run the following and deleted any relevant looking file (skipped stuff in `.rbenv` and project files, but deleted stuff in `/opt` and other directories) before reinstalling

`find /usr -name '*rabbitmq*'`

`find /Users -name '*rabbitmq*'`

`find / -name '*rabbitmq*'`

The first 2 are redundant if you run the last one, but it shortened the results so I feel they were worth running separately

Also restarted my computer between deleting files and reinstalling, but not sure if that affected anything